# FirebirdSql.Data.FirebirdClient.FbException: too many open handles to database

Tags: entity-framework, entity-framework-6, firebird

Today I did a larger data import into a firebird 2.5.6 database and I got this exception:

```
System.Data.Entity.Core.EntityCommandExecutionException: An error occurred while executing the command definition. See the inner exception for details. ---> FirebirdSql.Data.FirebirdClient.FbException: too many open handles to database ---> FirebirdSql.Data.Common.IscException: too many open handles to database
   bei FirebirdSql.Data.Client.Managed.Version10.GdsDatabase.ProcessResponse(IResponse response) in C:\Users\Jiri\Documents\devel\NETProvider\working\Provider\src\FirebirdSql.Data.FirebirdClient\Client\Managed\Version10\GdsDatabase.cs:Zeile 641.
   bei FirebirdSql.Data.Client.Managed.Version10.GdsDatabase.ReadResponse() in C:\Users\Jiri\Documents\devel\NETProvider\working\Provider\src\FirebirdSql.Data.FirebirdClient\Client\Managed\Version10\GdsDatabase.cs:Zeile 673.
   bei FirebirdSql.Data.Client.Managed.Version10.GdsDatabase.ReadGenericResponse() in C:\Users\Jiri\Documents\devel\NETProvider\working\Provider\src\FirebirdSql.Data.FirebirdClient\Client\Managed\Version10\GdsDatabase.cs:Zeile 681.
   bei FirebirdSql.Data.Client.Managed.Version11.GdsStatement.Prepare(String commandText) in C:\Users\Jiri\Documents\devel\NETProvider\working\Provider\src\FirebirdSql.Data.FirebirdClient\Client\Managed\Version11\GdsStatement.cs:Zeile 80.
   bei FirebirdSql.Data.FirebirdClient.FbCommand.Prepare(Boolean returnsSet) in C:\Users\Jiri\Documents\devel\NETProvider\working\Provider\src\FirebirdSql.Data.FirebirdClient\FirebirdClient\FbCommand.cs:Zeile 1169.
   bei FirebirdSql.Data.FirebirdClient.FbCommand.ExecuteCommand(CommandBehavior behavior, Boolean returnsSet) in C:\Users\Jiri\Documents\devel\NETProvider\working\Provider\src\FirebirdSql.Data.FirebirdClient\FirebirdClient\FbCommand.cs:Zeile 1190.
   bei FirebirdSql.Data.FirebirdClient.FbCommand.ExecuteReader(CommandBehavior behavior) in C:\Users\Jiri\Documents\devel\NETProvider\working\Provider\src\FirebirdSql.Data.FirebirdClient\FirebirdClient\FbCommand.cs:Zeile 527.
   --- Ende der internen Ausnahmestapelüberwachung ---
   bei FirebirdSql.Data.FirebirdClient.FbCommand.ExecuteReader(CommandBehavior behavior) in C:\Users\Jiri\Documents\devel\NETProvider\working\Provider\src\FirebirdSql.Data.FirebirdClient\FirebirdClient\FbCommand.cs:Zeile 533.
   bei FirebirdSql.Data.FirebirdClient.FbCommand.ExecuteDbDataReader(CommandBehavior behavior) in C:\Users\Jiri\Documents\devel\NETProvider\working\Provider\src\FirebirdSql.Data.FirebirdClient\FirebirdClient\FbCommand.cs:Zeile 639.
   bei System.Data.Common.DbCommand.ExecuteReader(CommandBehavior behavior)
   bei System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.Interception.DbCommandDispatcher.<Reader>b__c(DbCommand t, DbCommandInterceptionContext`1 c)
   bei System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.Interception.InternalDispatcher`1.Dispatch[TTarget,TInterceptionContext,TResult](TTarget target, Func`3 operation, TInterceptionContext interceptionContext, Action`3 executing, Action`3 executed)
   bei System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.Interception.DbCommandDispatcher.Reader(DbCommand command, DbCommandInterceptionContext interceptionContext)
   bei System.Data.Entity.Internal.InterceptableDbCommand.ExecuteDbDataReader(CommandBehavior behavior)
   bei System.Data.Common.DbCommand.ExecuteReader(CommandBehavior behavior)
   bei System.Data.Entity.Core.EntityClient.Internal.EntityCommandDefinition.ExecuteStoreCommands(EntityCommand entityCommand, CommandBehavior behavior)
   --- Ende der internen Ausnahmestapelüberwachung ---
   bei System.Data.Entity.Core.EntityClient.Internal.EntityCommandDefinition.ExecuteStoreCommands(EntityCommand entityCommand, CommandBehavior behavior)
   bei System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.Internal.ObjectQueryExecutionPlan.Execute[TResultType](ObjectContext context, ObjectParameterCollection parameterValues)
   bei System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.ObjectQuery`1.<>c__DisplayClass7.<GetResults>b__6()
   bei System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.ObjectContext.ExecuteInTransaction[T](Func`1 func, IDbExecutionStrategy executionStrategy, Boolean startLocalTransaction, Boolean releaseConnectionOnSuccess)
   bei System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.ObjectQuery`1.<>c__DisplayClass7.<GetResults>b__5()
   bei System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.DefaultExecutionStrategy.Execute[TResult](Func`1 operation)
   bei System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.ObjectQuery`1.GetResults(Nullable`1 forMergeOption)
   bei System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.ObjectQuery`1.<System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<T>.GetEnumerator>b__0()
   bei System.Data.Entity.Internal.LazyEnumerator`1.MoveNext()
   bei System.Linq.Enumerable.FirstOrDefault[TSource](IEnumerable`1 source)
   bei System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.ELinq.ObjectQueryProvider.<GetElementFunction>b__1[TResult](IEnumerable`1 sequence)
   bei System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.ELinq.ObjectQueryProvider.ExecuteSingle[TResult](IEnumerable`1 query, Expression queryRoot)
   bei System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.ELinq.ObjectQueryProvider.System.Linq.IQueryProvider.Execute[TResult](Expression expression)
   bei System.Data.Entity.Internal.Linq.DbQueryProvider.Execute[TResult](Expression expression)
   bei System.Linq.Queryable.FirstOrDefault[TSource](IQueryable`1 source)
```

Can someone explain what this `too many open handles to database` means? I never saw this before and [searching in google](https://www.google.de/search?q=%22too%20many%20handles%20to%20database%22) only [shows 1 old entry](http://www.jezzper.com/jezzper/Discussions.nsf/f72637182738a22ec1257082007010ef/b06ac4fbe7602200c1257797006961a4!OpenDocument).

Comment: Mark Rotteveel  explained it in his answer. Make sure that often use COMMIT when importing large amounts of data

Comment: @Majkl I do commits ;)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The error `isc_too_many_handles` or error 335544761 means what it says: you use too many handles.

Looking at the Firebird 3 code, [`server.cpp`](https://github.com/FirebirdSQL/firebird/blob/B3_0_Release/src/remote/server/server.cpp) (search for `isc_too_many_handles`), this error is raised if Firebird cannot allocate a handle for a statement, transaction, blob, or 'request' because you already have 65000 (`MAX_OBJCT_HANDLES`) handles allocated and in use on a single connection. Note that this number is for all handles on the connection together (not per type).

This can happen if you do too much of the following:

- create new statement handles without dropping (closing) statement handles you no longer need,
- start transactions but never commit or rollback (which deallocates the handle),
- open blobs without closing them (or opening a lot of blobs at once), and
- start 'requests' without deallocating them.

  AFAIK these 'requests' are used for embedded SQL support and some internal parts of Firebird itself; I'm not exactly sure how and when they are used, so I can't really comment on them. I guess it is not very likely the cause, but maybe when you already have a lot of statements, blobs and transactions these can be the final drop.

You might want to inspect your code for resource leaks, but as you seem to be using Entity Framework, it might also be that the Firebird .net entity framework support or ADO.net driver does something wrong. If you can reproduce it consistently, and you are sure you are closing resources timely, you might want to report a bug (with all necessary code + database to reproduce) on http://tracker.firebirdsql.org/browse/DNET

Comment: thanks for the detailed answer. I checked my code and I regular do commits after processing 1 file that I import (I parse ETL files with TraceEvent (https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.Diagnostics.Tracing.TraceEvent) and save my important events into DB because parsing the ETL is slow. And here I commit the changes after each .ETL. parsing the ETL takes 30-60s. After this I also dispose the context (I use using statement around the context). When I get an error during import I rolback the transaction to make sure the incomplete data from the ETL are not stored to the DB.

Comment: @magicandre1981 Are you storing or retrieving data to/from blobs?

Comment: no, I don't use blobs, I don't store the large ETL into the DB only my relevant parts. At the point were I see the error I only did a small query (FirstOrDefault call)

Comment: @magicandre1981 That doesn't really sound like something that I would expect to trigger this error. Could you post some code, or maybe send a message to the firebird-net-provider mailinglist, as this sounds like something that might take more back-and-forth than is suitable for stackoverflow.

Comment: I never saw this before and I was also confused. If I can ever find a way to repro I post here again. Until this I mark your reply as answer.

Comment: @magicandre1981 Is your application very long running? The Firebird .net provider is using a connection pool so the lifetime of a connection can be long, and maybe if something is leaking handles (either your code, or maybe internally in Firebird .net provider), that might eventually hit the limit as well.

Comment: yes, parsing several hundreds of the ETL files takes time, so the program runs several hours

Comment: the last months everything was fine and I coulkd parse several hundreds of ETL files and store the data in FB db, but now I get this exception after 30 files. I'll check the pooling tomorrow.

Comment: ok, setting *Pooling=false;* in connection string seams to work.