# is there any maximum DB connection set at the Firebird 2.5.9

Tags: php, firebird

We have OS - CentOS, PHP 5.2.5, Firebird 1.5, Apache 2.2.6 and running the 20 PHP files in single script; it's running fine here.

Now we have changed to OS - Red Hat, PHP 7.4.1, Firebird 2.5.9, Apache 2.5.9 and try to run the 20 PHP files in single script. We are facing the below issue.

> PHP Warning:  ibase_query(): too many open handles to database

We came to know that DB connections set default -- 65000 in one single connection, after reaching those many connections we are facing the above issue.

Can anyone help me to set the DB connections at the Firebird 2.5.9.

Comment: What do you mean with _"We came to know that DB connections set default -- 65000 in one single connection"_?

Comment: Your question seems to be a duplicate of [FirebirdSql.Data.FirebirdClient.FbException: too many open handles to database](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39148222/firebirdsql-data-firebirdclient-fbexception-too-many-open-handles-to-database). The problem isn't that you have too many connections, the problem is that you have too many handles open in a single connection (that is statements, blobs, transactions, and some internal objects). It means that you (or the ibase driver) isn't properly closing things when they are done with it.

Comment: We'd need to see a [mre] of the problem to be able to guess at a cause. You might also want to consider asking on https://groups.google.com/g/firebird-php instead.

Comment: @MarkRotteveel he may refer to the datatype limit of TCP/IP version 4 ports quantity per single IP

Comment: @Arioch'The The 'too many open handles to database' error is raised when allocating too many handles on a single connection and not closing any (or closing too few). Opening too many ports would likely raise a low-level socket error.

Comment: @MarkRotteveel well, he refered to "DB connections" and so did i. It is possible he is struggling with English in general or with chosing correct programming terms. At least client API has all handles as UInt32, not UInt16, and 65 000 clearly alludes to 65536

Comment: @Arioch'The And again, the error in question occurs when you allocate too many handles on single connection. Not if you create too many connections. As the duplicates points out, you cannot allocate more than 65000 handles on a connection. This is a hard limited defined through the `MAX_OBJCT_HANDLES` constant.